# i am trying to create a GET method in DRF similar to the SQL below with 3 tables by joining them together

Tags: python, sql, django-rest-framework

Get information about a patient's pending appointments, abbreviated as "ap", "dt", "sp" connection between the ids of each table. The condition is to get only appointments with 'Pending' status and only get information about a specific patient's appointment.

```
SELECT *
FROM appointment AS ap
INNER JOIN doctor AS dt ON ap.dt_id = dt.dt_id
INNER JOIN specialty AS sp ON dt .apm_id = sp .apm_id
WHERE ap.status= 'Pending' AND ap.patient_id = id;
```

Here i used the correct "filter", however i am not familiar with "select_related" and "prefetch_related", i think this is the problem i cant solve

```
def list_patient_pending(self, pk=None):
    get_appointment = appointment.objects.select_related(doctor, specialty).filter(status = "Pending", patient_id =pk)
    serializer = appointmentSerializer(get_appointment, many=True)
    return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
```

> Someone please help me to retrieve, thanks all